# Magento - Programmatically added products don't show up

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am trying to import products using a custom made import profile. Here I set some values on the product and then save it, like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$data = array();
// Inbetween I fill $data with some values
$product->addData($data);
$product->save();
```

However, the products **do** show up in the admin, but do **not** show up on the frontend (I did add them to categories).

The odd thing is, they do appear on the frontend once I open them in the admin and save them again (without modifying anything). Am I forgetting something, or some value that is somehow set by that action?

I tried to rebuild all indices in the backend and to clear the cache, but this does not work, contrary to [Magento API: Rebuild Indexes after adding new products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343739/magento-api-rebuild-indexes-after-adding-new-products/4343900#4343900).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some [guesses](http://masteringmagento.com/2010/04/8-and-a-half-reasons-your-magento-products-dont-show-up-in-the-catalog/), since this comes up from time to time. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493141/magento-products-will-not-show-in-category).

Comment: Thanks, it might be because it is not enabled on the website.. All other things are alright. I have yet to figure out how to do that though.

Comment: Thanks, they are visible now, had to set the website_ids property. Nice blog by the way!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding the Website ID to the product:

```
$newProduct ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
```

Keep in mind that the parameter is an array, so you can add multiple website td's