# Magento - problem displaying imported products

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a custom script that takes data form an XML and loads in the products.

The main problem, is that these products do display on the frontend.

The only way they do, is if i go into the admin and open the product and then save it.

I noticed that once i did this, an entry was added into the table 'catalog_product_flat_1'.

Is there a way to either display these imported products or add them to the 'catalog_product_flat_1' table without having to save each product?

I am using Magento v1.4.2

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento API: Rebuild Indexes after adding new products](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343739/magento-api-rebuild-indexes-after-adding-new-products)

Comment: That looks very similar to my question. However, even when i manually re-index via the admin, none of my products display on the frontend

Comment: What about [Programmatically added products don't show up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4555371/471559)? That also wasn't fixed by re-indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go to Index Management and do the Product Flat Data reindexing. Also, do you have one-store or multi-store system? If its the later see what is set under the Websites for each product.

Comment: I have gone and re-indexed the data. I have a single store. The main problem seems to be that, when I import, I see products in admin. I see none on frontend. I only see products once I've saved them in the admin. I am setting the store id using: $product->setStoreId(1); Is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: If clearing all cache and reindexing is not helping you, try Export all products using the built-in Magento option. There then you can see the difference between those that are visible in your shop and those that are only in the admin.

Comment: It seems that I was not setting the website id using `setWebsiteIds();`

Answer (score 0):

i had also same problem. it was not showing product after re indexing. but after adding this two field in CSV

1)_root_category = Default Category

and

2)_product_websites = base

i import CSV. it solve problem and start displays product in store.