# Magento massive product import cache & performance issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am importing about 10.000 products and updating their data with import custom script on regular basic. I use Magento object to save product data. The problem is that for each product save the process is slower. On 1000 products save it becomes really slow. When I clear cache, everything is ok again.

I have now couple of questions to understand the thing:

1. Does anybody have any idea why is that?
2. Should I disable "Collections Data" cache, or maybe any other type of cache as well?
3. Or is there any way to tell Magento not to cache collection data on product save?
4. If not, will disabling Collections Data cache slow the page a lot?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the slowness is your indexes are getting larger.  Unless specified Magento will reindex for each new product, you can speed this up during your imports by disabling it, however you will need to reindex at some point to be able to present the newly imported products to the frontend.

A solution to consider:

- [Magento API: Rebuild Indexes after adding new products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343739/magento-api-rebuild-indexes-after-adding-new-products)

Comment: But aren't indexes stored in db anyway? So let's say I already have 30.000 products in Magento. Their data is already indexed and if I update 1000 products, it won't make larger database, it will just refresh data. Isn't like that? But if I clear cache, this is not the case. In this case it will be actually 1000 new data in disk. That is why I think it is about cache and not index.

Comment: Also only when I flush cache import and product save speed is ok again, reindex doesn't make any impact.